# Foreach loop but print one time with multiple value

Tags: php

So I have in my database a table called `"Clients"` and an other one called `"Pets"`.
They are linked by an associative table which means that a `"Clients"` can have two `"Pets"`.

I am using a `FOREACH` loop to display my client and pets but when a client have many pets, my foreach loop print everything, as many as the client have pets.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjnTg.png)

here is my `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($files as $file) :
echo $file['address'];
endforeach
```

My problem is that I want to have everything diplayed normally except the `"pets"` (`<?= $file['petName']; ?>`) and see that the client have 2 pets..

[like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szz5i.png)

Thanks for your help !

My SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.idClients = clients.idClients
LEFT JOIN pets ON pets.idPets = owners.idPets
LEFT JOIN clientsdocs ON clientsdocs.idClients = clients.idClients
WHERE clients.idClients='$id'
```

Comment: Please post your SQL query with the question

Comment: If it's relevant. If it's not, remove the <sql> tag.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I dit it, "owner" is my associative table  and "clientsdocs" it's an other table which we don't need it for this problem

Comment: Could you show a representative sample of `$files` - use `var_export($files)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change query like:

```
SELECT
    clients.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(petName) AS petsNames # implode pets names s into 1 string
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.idClients = clients.idClients
LEFT JOIN pets ON pets.idPets = owners.idPets
LEFT JOIN clientsdocs ON clientsdocs.idClients = clients.idClients
GROUP BY clients.idClients # this is group all client's data in single row
WHERE clients.idClients='$id';
```

It's not solution, but can can give you an idea for best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, this what I wanted, thanks a lot !

here the modified code :

```
SELECT *, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT petName ORDER BY petName) AS petsNames
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.idClients = clients.idClients
LEFT JOIN pets ON pets.idPets = owners.idPets
LEFT JOIN clientsdocs ON clientsdocs.idClients = clients.idClients
WHERE clients.idClients='$id'
```